# Add child to parent component that is not visible in flex

Tags: apache-flex, inheritance, mxml

I have a mxml file that extends a parent class. The parent has a component that is hidden initially and only shown once a button is pressed. I would like to add a new child component to this hidden component from my extended mxml. Is there a way to access the super component and add the child once the buton is pressed? Maybe listen to an event?

Right now i have a solution that solves the problem by loading the hidden components but it´s not a nice solution.

```
super.advancedOptionsSearchBox.getChildren();
super.advancedOptionsSearchBox.addChildAt(getEANContainer(), 1);
```

If i do not call the getChildren I get a index out of bounds exception on the call to addChildAt method since the array of children is empty in the hidden component.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just set property

```
creationPolicy="all"
```

to your component? That way it's created even if it's initially not visible.

Comment: this would be a the best way but there is too much to load in the sub-children in the accordian and it will be a little bit to slow in the loading process.